# Tailwindcss with postcss and css modules

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss, css-modules

I was thinking that Tailwind CSS with CSS modules / post css will work nicely together. to write less code and generate less CSS but...

when I used tailwind with @apply it just applies styles to that class

example

```
.root {
  @apply flex align-center;
}
```

from styles.root to "root flex align-center"
but instead it just add css to .root class

I think that it should work as `composes: flex align-center from global;`

Is my configuration wrong or it's just working in that way?

Answer (score 1):

That is just how the [`@apply` directive](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) works. `@apply` is used to inline any existing utility classes into your own custom CSS.

```css
/* Input */
.root {
    @apply flex items-center;
}

/* Output */
.root {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: yeah I know, so there is no way to use tailwind effectively? only with composes from global?

Comment: What do you mean by "using tailwind effectively"?

Comment: with @apply we are adding more and more CSS instead of just reusable classes, exactly your example, you want to use just flex and align-center but it just adds the code for that...

Comment: You can create your own utility classes (like the one above), then reuse those instead. Ultimately, you'll always get the Tailwind classes converted to CSS anyway.

Comment: so I need to create utility classes from utility classes :D the best way should be to work it as `composes: flex items-center from tailwind` you don't want to add more and more css to codebase

Answer (score 0):

I found better approach that you looking for. You can define `styles.ts` or `styles.js` instead of `styles.module.css`. It also support Tailwind intellisense.

Define tailwind classes inside `ts`/`js` file like this:

```js
const styles = {
    card: 'rounded-3xl shadow',
    headings: 'relative overflow-hidden'
};

export default styles;
```

Then import to your Javascript/Typescript file, e.g JSX Components:

```js
import styles from './styles';
export default function Card() {
  <div className={styles.card}>
    <h3 className={styles.headings}>
      Hello world
    </h3>
  </div>
}
```

You can also add this to settings.json if you have Tailwind Intellisense so it will give you autocomplete inside the `style.js`:

```json
"tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": 
[
  [
    "const styles\\s*=\\s*{([\\s\\S]*)}",
    ":\\s?\\n?[\\s]*?['\"`]([^'\"`]*)['\"`]"
  ]
],
```

Disclaimer: this is just workarounds to separate your styling file and your javascript logic/component files, because CSS Modules actually behaves differently (combining styles into one unique class across the project). This way you can still have utility classes shown inside your html = actual tailwind classes.

Actually you can also use `.json` instead of this but you need to tweak the tailwind intellisense a little bit, also by using js instead of json, by default most of frameworks/libraries out there will always minify your js file in production, just like css.